# Using the SQL initialization hook with ManytoManyField

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm fairly new to Django and I'm trying to add some 'host' data to 'record' using django's hook for using SQL to initialise (a SQL file in lowercase in the app folder & sql subfolder)

Here's the models:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    species = models.TextField(max_length = 80)
    data=models.TextField(max_length = 700)
    hosts = models.ManyToManyField('Host')

class Host(models.Model):
    hostname = models.TextField()
```

I've used a ManyToManyField as each record should be able to have multiple hosts, and hosts should be 'reusable': ie be able to appear in many records.

When I'm trying to insert via SQL I have

```
INSERT INTO myapp_record VALUES ('Species name', 'data1', XYZ);
```

I'm not sure what to put for XYZ (the ManytoMany) if I wanted hosts 1, 2 and 3 for example

Separating them by commas doesn't work obviously, and I tried a tuple and neither did that. 
Should I be trying to insert into the intermediary table Django makes? Does that have a similar hook to the one I'm using? If not, how can I execute SQL inserts on this table?

Comment: If I do that, the initialization for Record complains (rightfully) about missing one value (the host field). I suppose I could allow the hosts field to be null at first and then add it to the intermediary but I was under the impression the point of Django handling that was that I shouldn't.

I also have a couple hundred lines to manually do then, so if there's any way to do that at the same time as inserting into record that is what I would prefer, I will of course do what I must if required.

Answer (score 0):

The use of initial SQL data files is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data). Instead, you should be using a data migration, which might look something like this:

```
from django.db import models, migrations

def create_records(apps, schema_editor):
    # We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
    # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
    Record = apps.get_model("yourappname", "Record")
    Host = apps.get_model("yourappname", "Host")
    host1 = Host.objects.get(hostname='host1')
    record = Record.objects.create(name='Species name', data='Data')
    record.hosts.add(host1)
    ...etc...

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_records),
    ]
```

Comment: I hope you can understand that I'm pretty reluctant to move to a new version of Django (that's sub 1 week old no less) to use a system that would require a relatively large undertaking and shift in knowledge to implement into a solution. With basically no newbie support outside of the official docs at the moment and working under the assumption that what i want can be done rather simply with just some syntax i don't have you can surely see why I won't be doing this.